# Laravel: Can't set object values

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form in Laravel that when it submits, the function `donorUpdate` is going to be called, and it will save the data to the database. Here is the *exact* code of the function.

My aim is, the form contains the field name `DonorPrefix` that when it's empty, the default value should be `Mx.`. I have tried the code below, and it doesn't work.

```
public function donorUpdate(Request $request, Donor $donor){
  if($request->has('DonorPrefix') == false || $request->DonorPrefix == '' || $request->DonorPrefix == null){
    $request->DonorPrefix = 'Mx.';
  }
  $donor->update($request->all());
  return redirect('/donor/'.$donor->DonorID);
}
```

This is where the *weird* part start: My debugging attempt is that I commented the `return redirect('/donor/'.$donor->DonorID);` line and replace with `return $request->all()`, the value for `DonorPrefix` is `""` (Empty string).

However when I tried `return $request->DonorPrefix`, the prefix `Mx.` returned.

Why isn't the value of `DonorPrefix` is `Mx.` on `$request->all()`, but is `Mx.` on `return $request->DonorPrefix`?

Edit: I'm certain that other parts of code works like charm. Things are smooth untill I tried adding this 'default value' function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *set* request parameters like `$request->DonorPrefix = '...'`.

To set a parameter on the request you need to use `offsetSet` like this:

```
$request->offsetSet('DonorPrefix', 'Mx.');
```

Also, the `has()` method already ensures that it is a *non-empty string* so you can remove some of your checks, and simplify your code like this:

```
if(!$request->has('DonorPrefix')){
    $request->offsetSet('DonorPrefix', 'Mx.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!